# Neo4jClient create node exception

Tags: neo4jclient

Can anyone point out why I get an exception when the .results point in the code is executed?

-- note the code has been edited after the quested was answered as per Tatham Oddie's comment. ---

```
    public User Create(User user) 
    {
        try
        {
            // Check if user exists
            if (this.Exists(user.EmailAddress))
            {
                throw new Exception("User already exists");
            }
            else
            {
                var q = this._context.Client().Cypher
                    .Create("(n:User {f}")
                    .WithParam("f", "Mike")
                    .Return(n => n.As<User>());

                return q.Results.Single();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Know the throwed exception could help a little... No?
And, you should console.log(q) just before the return.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not write code like this: `"(n:User {FirstName: '" + user.FirstName + "'}"`. It is ***a major security risk in your application***, and a performance constraint.

Follow the example at https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples#create-a-user which uses a parameter syntax.

1. It will be secure.
2. It will be faster.
3. It will work.

Comment: Absolutely, parameter usage for security (eliminate injection), as well as query caching. I was testing neo4j and asked for that purpose. Thank you

Comment: But when you publish insecure code like that here, other people see it and copy it. Please always avoid that type of code, even if you're just testing.

Answer (score -1):

Got it. Syntax error. Missing bracket.